# Why is the executable size the same when linking shared vs static library?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

So, I was studying about `static` library vs `shared` library and came to know that an `executable` linked with static library is bigger in size because static library actually becomes part of the executable. While, In case of shared library, It is not the part of the executable and is linked at runtime. However, when linking static vs shared library, size of the executable is same in both cases. Here is my code:

root/CMakeLists.txt :-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(hello_world)
add_executable(my_app main.cpp)
add_subdirectory( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
target_link_libraries(my_app   PRIVATE   my_lib)
target_include_directories(my_app PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)
```

main.cpp :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include "mymath.h"

int main() {
    std::cout<<sum(2,4)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<mul(2,4);
}
```

lib/CMakeLists.txt :-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(my_lib SHARED math.cpp) //size of my_app doesn't change when I use 
                                 // STATIC here
target_include_directories(my_lib PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include)
```

lib/math.cpp :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include "mymath.h"
int sum(int a, int b) {
return a+b;
}
int mul(int a, int b) {
return a*b;
}
```

Comment: Just guessing, but executable often have alignment requirements for their internal data, and any size differences resulting from such a small library might be hidden by padding to reach the required alignment.

Comment: Probably too small of a library to make a big difference.

Comment: Also, this application doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does; `'\n'` ends a line. And is needed after the second line, too; formally, a newline is required at the end of the output from a program.

Comment: Your library is very small. When not linking statically, the exe must instead hold info about what dynamic library to use. Also takes some space. I also believe that executable files grow in blocks, like kBytes at a time, so you get some round off errors.

Comment: I was checking the size in bytes using "ls -l" and it's exactly the same bytes. I know the library is too small but I expected a difference of a few bytes.

Comment: As @BoP was saying, files grow by blocks, not by bytes. The difference in size would have to be at least that of a block size before noticing a difference in the byte size.

Comment: I am building it on my Mac M1 Pro using "make" and "make" commands.

Comment: Are you using clang?

Answer (score 3):

In short, this library is too small to make a difference.

If you're compiling on a mac, as you indicate in the comments, this would likely have to do with memory alignment in the generated binary.

MacOS uses the Mach-O format for executable images, which include a header followed by load commands describing various things about the program, for instance the segment and section layouts (and alignment), the location of the main function, the symbol table location, any referenced libraries and the dynamic linker which loads them, etc. (these are described in `mach-o/loader.h`)

Generally, this is all placed in the `__TEXT,__text` section of a standard executable, and if you take a look at the header referenced above, you'll note that the size of the `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` command is 24 bytes + the size of the library name (here, something like `@rpath/libmy_lib.dylib` most likely). So, to reference a single library, you need something like 32 bytes of space in the generated image.

Meanwhile, the library code generated on my M1 machine from your math.cpp file is abound 64 bytes. So including this code in the image takes about 64 bytes. This is included in the same segment as the load command for the dynamic library.

So why is the generated size the same? Segment alignment. On an M1 system, each memory page is 16 kb in length, and each segment in the binary is aligned to a 16kb boundary (this is declared in the segment load commands, but in general ld will pick 16kb alignment). That is to say that at a minimum the text segment will take 16kb in memory. Here, because your code is so small, it doesn't fill up the entire 16kb segment with either dynamic.  Therefore, it doesn't really matter if you choose to link statically or dynamically, you'll always get a 16kb `__TEXT` segment including either an extra load command or a bit more code.

On the other hand, if your library was more than 16kb of raw instructions, you would notice a difference in the generated file size, as dynamic linking would require still only ~32 bytes for a single load command whereas your library would require at least a second page in the `__TEXT` segment.